Lock one option on checkbox filter in spotfire using data function
I have a checkbox filter with say 10 options. I want option#1 to be always selected(possibly locked) and the user has flexibility to select other options. How can I do this using data function(not ironpython)?
(I have not used python with spotfire and i see some suggestions with iron python in stack overflow. But I want this to be implemented via a data function as I dont have an option to write iron python code in spotfire)

I cannot see a way to control filters with a data function. Maybe you can try javascript but I am not an expert there.
